# How to receive the response of scrapy.Request() in the same function it is called from?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I am quite new to Scrapy and have this requirement where I need the response of the Scrapy Request back to the function it is getting called from.
Currently I found only 1 solution for this by using scrapy-inline-requests library

Is there any native way for this in Scrapy?

For Example

```
def parse(self, response):
    item = spiderItem()

    # Extract some items here from this response using CSS Selectors
    # ....
    # ....

    # Now extract URL from the response
    new_url = response.css("div.urls::text").get()
    yield scrapy.Request(new_url, callback=self.parse_more)

    # Receive the response from parse_more() here. Is it possible?
    resp = 

def parse_more(self, response):
    # This function should be able to return the response back to the parse() function for further processing.
```

Something like what we are able to do in requests Library

```
response = requests.get(url)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Scrapy was built on top of the Twisted async library, don't think it's possible. The callback method gets invoked with the HTTP response without blocking the calling thread.